# Static languages and Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-programming, language-features

As far as i know and understand,

**Reflection** is the ability to create/modify source code at run time.

From Wikipedia:

- Discover and modify source code constructions (such as code blocks,
  classes, methods, protocols, etc.) as a first-class object at
  runtime.
- Convert a string matching the symbolic name of a class or    function
  into a reference to or invocation of that class or function.
- Evaluate a string as if it were a source code statement at runtime.
  Create a new interpreter for the language's bytecode to give a new
  meaning or purpose for a programming construct.

**Dynamic languages** are languages that we can eval (evaluate direct from string) at run-time.

From wikipedia:
"extension of the program, by adding new code, by extending objects and definitions, or by modifying the type system"

Ok, now, my question is:
How static languageד (without eval ability) can have reflection (e.g Java)? (the new source code doesn't evaluate? :/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Java has a byte code manipulation library called [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). Reflection isn't used to add new code like you are describing in your question.

Comment: Reflection allows to tamper (yes, it can be harmful in some cases) with a class by querying about its methods, fields, access levels and such but _you do not generate new code_. It has other uses like, for example, invoking a method defined in certain class based only on data about it (*metadata*). You get an instance from a class, you get a method from it based on its firm and then you invoke it.

Comment: @Gamb 10x, but if u modify a source code, so u generate a source code (as wikipedia says), aren't we?

Comment: Except you don't do that with reflection. For example, Hibernate generates code using cglib, by manipulating byte code, not source code.

Comment: Java actually nowadays has a native compiler API that can be called during runtime at will. Language being static has pretty much nothing to do with its construct loading capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think wikipedia explanation is not really phrased well.

Reflection (or introspection) is not about creation of code during runtime but rather about ability of code to *reflect on itself* in runtime (and modify it's behavior based on this). Examples would be getting info about type of the object (like RTTI in C++) or getting metadata associated with object (like annotations in Java).

Runtime code generation is more related to *first-classness* than to reflection, so I would argue that current wikipedia article is kind of misleading.

**UPDATE**

In other words answer to this:

> Ok, now, my question is, how can static language (without eval ability) can have reflection (e.g Java)?

... would be that reflection does not rely on evel ability. These are 2 separate language features.

And also, as Giulio Franco pointed out in the comments - Java is capable of runtime code generation\manipulation (see [CGLIB](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) for example).

Comment: I'd like to add that Java classes are loaded at run-time, and there is a Java class which allows you to compile and load a Java class on the fly. So, actually, Java **can** add code at runtime. Maybe you can also remove, modify, and reload a class, but I think this has got some limitations (maybe you can't unload a currently used class).